# Search Records in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem on how to search records in datagridview. This is my sample code.

```
Private Sub txtStit_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtStit.TextChanged
    Dim sqlsearch As String
    sqlsearch = "SELECT * FROM tblList WHERE [Book Title] LIKE '%" & txtStit.Text & "%'"

    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlsearch, con)

    Dim dt As New DataTable("tblList")
    adapter.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView3.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Actually it works but my problem is whenever I clicked or move the cursor outside the textbox the records that I didn`t searched are showing.

thnk u guys

[visual studio 2008, mcaccess 2007]

Comment: Is the txtStit_TextChanged method the only place you set the DataSource for DataGridView3?

Comment: Do you have some others Event handlers for your `TextBox`(`txtStit`)? Maybe for events `.LostFocus` or `.Leave` or some else?

Comment: the only that I used is _TextChanged ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you understand, there is no way to appear records that you did not ask for. You asked it somehow, implicitly or explicitly. I bet you have set the datasource of the `DataGridView3` using a wizard or an explicit query somewhere else. I would suggest debugging using breakpoints on different events of the application lifecycle. Using the breakpoints, you can identify where the change of the datasource happens. I would start from `Form.Load` event...

Hope I helped!

Comment: thnks for advise sir. i`d checked my code and I found my own mistake.

Comment: Glad to help. Please upvote the answer. It is important for users navigating to your question to be able to spot the helpful answers easily.

Answer (score 1):

TextChanged is firing with each keystroke.   Try moving it to KeyUp

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Return Then
     Put your code here
 End If
```